# Combobox dropDown selected

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a `ComboBox` which also gets controlled by two buttons. But I would like to separate the execution from using the `ComboBox` dropdown and the buttons.

```
comboBox3.DropDownClosed += (b, f) =>
{
    week = Convert.ToInt16(comboBox3.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(week);
};
```

I tried this approach but it seems to be not updating the week when the dropdown gets closed and selecting another value.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking but why not use SelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: I would suggest sticking to SelectedIndexChanged. If you need to block exectution of the SelectedIndexChanged when one of your Buttons got clicked just simply use a boolean that wraps the SelectedIndex = 2; in your button click.

Comment: *[`SelectionChangeCommitted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event is raised only when the user changes the combo box selection, and you can create a handler for this event to provide special handling for the ComboBox when the user changes the selected item in the list.*

Comment: Well it counts selectIndexChange when i use buttons aswell.

Comment: You should write different methods to do different things, for example, `Button1.Click` should call `Action1`, `Button2.Click` should call `Action2` and `ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted` should call `Action3`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei your solution works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something when user changes the selected index of the `ComboBox`, you need to handle [`SelectionChangeCommitted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event (and not `SelectedIndexChanged`):

> The `SelectionChangeCommitted` event is raised only when the user changes
>   the combo box selection, and you can create a handler for this event
>   to provide special handling for the `ComboBox` when the user changes the
>   selected item in the list.

In the other hand, `SelectedIndexChanged` will raise whenever the user or code changes the selected index.

So, instead of handling `SelectedIndexChanged`, you should write different methods to do different things, for example, handle `Button1.Click` and call `Action1`, handle `Button2.Click` and call `Action2` and handle `ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted` to detect when user changes the selected index and call `Action3`.